# How to put in map according to array?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, dictionary

I've got 2 maps and 1 array. First map is empty and second is full of data. Array includes some String keys. So I want to put data from second map to 1st if there are some equals keys in array.

**Example:**

*1st map:* empty

*2nd map(key,value):* foo,1; bar,2; java,3; pojo,4; tom,5; jerry,6;

*array(string):* foo,java,pojo;

So I need to put *(foo,1;java,3;pojo,4;)* in 1st map.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us some code, and tell us what didn't work?

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map1= new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> map2= new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map2.put("foo", 1);
    map2.put("bar", 2);
    map2.put("java", 3);
    map2.put("pojo", 4);
    map2.put("tom", 5);
    map2.put("jerry", 6);

    String[] arr={"foo","java","pojo"};

    for (String arrItem : arr)
    {
        map1.put(arrItem, map2.get(arrItem));
        System.out.println(arrItem);
        System.out.println(map2.get(arrItem));
    }

}
```

Vote up / Accept the answer if this solves your query

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for(String key : array) { 
    map2.put(key,map1.get(key);
}
```

Assuming all keys in the `array` actually exist in `map1`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your after?

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    if(myMap2.get(myArray[i])!=null)
        myMap1.put(myArray[i], myMap2.get(myArray[i])); 
}
```